# Tools for Apache Cordova (VS'13) installing endlessly

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

This is really more of a configuration question, but believe me when I say I've searched all over for info on this issue. I've been trying to install "Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2013 CPT 3.0" for about an hour and a half now. It's been stuck on "Applying: Android SDK".

[image: This shows where it's been stuck for awhile now..]

Does it normally take this long? And, if not, any particular steps I should take to clear out some files?

Comment: I remember I tried to install cordova too (just wondering), but it's not finished somehow (for hours). and I had to cancel the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how long it took, but the Android SDK and emulator images are over 1GB, so it will take awhile.